# Django apps not showing in admin when site is deployed to server

Tags: django, mod-wsgi

I have a test site which I am (trying) to get deployed to an Ubuntu 16.04 server.

If I run the site using the Django server (python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000), I can see all of the apps when I visit the admin page as the superuser, and everything is fine.

However, when I run the site normally, using wsgi, the only apps I can see (and interact with) in the admin are for the users and groups. None of the apps I have created are visible, and if I try and navigate to a change list page for one of them for example, I get a page not found.

I believe my mod_wsgi set up is ok, in that I can view the admin and login, so I don't believe this is the problem.

Perhaps it's a permissions issue?

Any help much appreciated!

**UPDATE**

In the django shell, on the server, I have run

```
from django.conf import settings
print(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
```

and this prints out the list of apps I would expect to be displayed in the admin

**UPDATE 2**

Having come back to the live site overnight, the apps are now showing in the admin - but I have no idea why, because they weren't yesterday and I haven't made any changes.

Comment: Did you create a superuser in production?

Comment: HI Daniel, many thanks for getting back. Yes, I actually have 2 superusers - one I set up originally and which I logged in with, and the other created separately by that superuser. Neither of them can view the apps.

Comment: Hi Daniel, Having come back to the test site overnight, all of the apps are now showing in the admin! I have no idea why! Many thanks for getting back.